# How to target html elements when using Vite?

Tags: css, vite

I have a very simple setup where I have to build a couple of HTML pages.  I threw Vite in since its the latest.  I have everything working except I can't target html tags.  They have to have a class or ID on them.

So this works:

```
<p class="paragraph">Some text</p>
.paragraph{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

This does not:

```
<p>Some text</p>
p{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

My vite.config is pretty simple as well:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path';

import handlebars from 'vite-plugin-handlebars';

    export default defineConfig({
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            additionalData: `
              @import "./style.scss";
           `
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        handlebars({
          partialDirectory: resolve(__dirname, 'partials'),
        }),
      ],
    })
```

I don't target a ton of these but its been a random nagging issue for a few days that I haven't been able to sort out.

TIA

Comment: does it work without handlebars?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev no.

Comment: If you inspect the `<p>Some text</p>` element in your console, what css rule is styling the font size of your paragraph tag? And does your `p` css exist but is being over ridden by heir-achy of css rules? Can you share your compiled vite style.css?